# Best solution for file folders of custom wooden desk drawer?

Tags: construction, hanging, desk

A few months ago, I bought a wooden desk.  I want to put file folders in one of the drawers.  I bought this file folder frame set (the kind you build) for file folders from Office Depot, but they don't work.  I bought a box of 500 file folders at Office Depot, and 20 feet away, they had these file folder frames.  The file folders are too small to even hang on the file folder frame set.

I've seen some different models that seem more durable than the frame set you construct.  They are merely clips that fit onto the side of your drawer.  I'd like to go that approach, if it'll work.  If you've done this before or can steer me in the right direction given my dimensions below, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I just haven't found any good pictures online with an actual drawer.  They just have sketches.  What have you done that has worked well for hanging file folders?  What would you recommend for me given the dimensions below?

**Here is what I found so far:**

http://www.hafele.com/us/products/hanging-file-rail-systems.asp

http://www.oodlesofpartsplus.com/hanging_plastic_file_rail_design.htm

**Dimensions of desk drawer:**

width (outside to outside): 14 1/4"

width (inside of drawer): 13 1/4"

height (inside of drawer): 10 3/4"

depth (inside of drawer): 18 1/2"

**Office Depot file folder dimensions:**

11 3/4" (inside dimension of where folder sits on rail)

12 7/16" (outside dimension of where folder sits on rail)

Answer (score 3):

I did my own with a simple steel rod, the kind you can find in different lenghts and diameters in a any hardwarestore.

I cutted the rods to match my drawer width, drilled 2 holes on both sides of my drawer (without going all the way through), inserted the rods and voilà: a simple file drawer.